# Rewrite without itertools just plain python

Tags: python

How do I rewrite this piece of code so that it doesnt use itertools (just simple python probably in more than one line, without using yield)?

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([node] * (indeg[node] + 1) for node in graph.keys()))
```

Comment: The equivalent code is part of the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Answer (score 0):

In this context `itertools.chain` just serves as a way to flatten a nested list (or generator)

```
In [266]: keys
Out[266]: [0, 1, 2, 3]

In [267]: indeg=[6,4,2,0]

In [269]: ll=[[node] * (indeg[node] + 1) for node in keys]

In [270]: ll
Out[270]: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3]]
```

a simple loop that would do the same flattening is:

```
In [271]: result=[]
In [272]: for i in ll: result.extend(i)
In [273]: result
Out[273]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

I'm not aware of a comprehension like expression that would accomplish the same.  Python cookbook(s) may have this, though the convenience of the `chain` may have religated that to history.

`reduce add` gives a one line flattener:

```
In [285]: import operator
In [286]: reduce(operator.add, ll, [])
Out[286]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

This is like a repeated `result += i`, which for lists is the same as `extend`.

Working from the comment:

```
In [289]: [j for i in ll for j in i]
Out[289]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

or the original as a double iteration:

```
In [290]: [j for node in keys for j in [node] * (indeg[node] + 1)]
Out[290]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It would be a LC with two iteration clauses.